# /Recent does not return LastAccessedDateTime

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/recent
```

only returns created time and last modified time from `fileSystemInfo` in the response as below:

```
"fileSystemInfo": {
  "createdDateTime": "2018-05-14T10:15:21Z",
  "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-05-14T10:15:00Z"
}
```

But not the `lastAccessedDateTime` [as documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/drive_recent).

1. Does Microsoft Graph Recent API capture and include in its response a read-only file open event?  Or is it limited to only the file modified or uploaded events?
2. I can see that `FileSystemInfo` class has a property called `LastAccessedDateTime`. If `Recent` API does not return this, what is the alternative way to query and retrieve it?

Answer (score 0):

The `lastAccessedDateTime` property only applies to consumer OneDrive, not SharePoint or OneDrive for Business. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/resources/filesysteminfo#remarks):

> **lastAccessedDateTime** is not available for items in SharePoint online or OneDrive for Business.

Comment: Thanks Marc for the clarification. Can you also provide some insight to my first question ? If I open up a file without modifying it, in my OneDrive for Business, will it be captured and returned by Recent api ? Or Recent api only returns modified files in OneDrive for Business ?

Comment: No. It will only update the `lastModifiedDateTime` if the file is altered in some way.

Comment: OK so there is no way to find recently opened/viewed files for OneDrive Business?

Comment: Not using this endpoint, no. If you really need granular control/auditing of a set of files, using SharePoint would be a better option. SharePoint gives you more control over file settings than OneDrive.

Comment: I asked a separate question in SO about alternative ways to retrieve accessed files in OneDrive for Business. Could you have a look and provide some insights there if you are knowledgeable in this specific issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50340456/how-to-get-recently-accessed-onedrive-for-business-files