# How to get recently accessed OneDrive for Business files?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I would like to get a list of both opened (without edit) and modified files.

I looked at `/Recent` api from Microsoft Graph and it does not return the recently viewed files for OneDrive Business, but only the modified files.

I also looked at: `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/insights/used`

This api on the paper does exactly what I needed, it returns `lastAccessedDateTime`

```
 "lastUsed": {
                "lastAccessedDateTime": "2018-05-03T15:31:53.913Z",
                "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-04-27T14:50:04.066Z"
            },
```

BUT... The results it returns are incomplete.. It does not return the latest files I opened. Hopefully these issues will be fixed once it is released in v1.0.

Is there a way to get a list of recently accessed, opened files in One Drive for Business either using Microsoft Graph or One Drive / Sharepoint api s ?

Comment: Hey, did you manage how to get the latest files I opened? Have the same issue.